# How to Show Cart Discount in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to Show Cart Discount in magento 2, without using any extension  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this file.

> /vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

Copy below code.

```
<item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/cart/totals/discount</item>
   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount</item>
   </item>
</item>
```

Paste this in your theme `checkout_cart_index.xml`.

And it will be working fine.

Happy Coding.

Comment: This code already there, but its not working

Comment: Please remove generated folder from the root and run all the commands.